# Count up in larger increments

Tags: c#

This is my current code but i've noticed i can't make it say count up and deduct specific amounts, just 1...

```
//Pernix Buttons
private void Pernix1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        CountP++;
        PernixL1.Text = CountP.ToString();
    }
    else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (CountP > 0)
            CountP--;
        PernixL1.Text = CountP.ToString();
    }

}
```

How would i go about making it so the click counts up in say 80's and deducts 80's as well?

Comment: use arithmetic operators

Comment: What is the issue ? or you don't know how to add `80` to your current value.

Comment: Use `CountP += 80;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The increment/decrement operators will +/- the value by 1. If you want to use different increments you will need to use arithmetic operators.

For example, to add 80 use `CountP += 80` instead of  `CountP++`

Answer (score 3):

looks like you are fairly new to programming.
I took your code and adopted it:

```
//Pernix Buttons
private void Pernix1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int sizePerClick = 80;
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
    {
        CountP+=sizePerClick;
        PernixL1.Text = CountP.ToString();
    }
    else if(e.Button==MouseButtons.Right)
    {
        if (CountP > 0)
            CountP-=sizePerClick;
        PernixL1.Text = CountP.ToString();
    }

}
```

The operators x-=y and x+=y are similar to using an expression like x=x+y (or x=x-y respectively).

Hope that helps.
Cheers,

Kristof

Answer (score 2):

Count++ means actually count=count+1  so to increment by 80 you use simply:

```
count = count + 80;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have some variable

```
int count=0;
```

want to increse value? simply incresae it by saying:

```
count=count+80;
```

count is equal to the value of count + 80

Once you get lazy you can say

```
    count+=80;

    //same goes with 1
    count=count+1    //increments by 1
    //or  
    count+=1;        //increments by 1
    //or
    count++;         //increments by 1
    //or
    ++count;         //increments by 1
```

but watch out for [++count](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/increment-operator) it behaves differently sometimes.

You can also decrease, multiply or divide  values the same way `count=count-80; count=count*80;  count=count/80;`
No need for confusion, it's just like on peace of paper xd